# How to update my Django website I deployed by DigitalOcean

Tags: django, deployment, updates, digital-ocean

I deployed my first Django website on the Internet. Now, I have made some updates in the local environment (I cloned the website from GitHub and did coding in VSCode). Once I deployed it a week ago, the environment was Django, Postgresql, Nginx, Gunicorn, and DigitalOcean as a VPS.
I am wondering that all I have to do is to command 'git pull' or 'git clone' here (I put a picture of the terminal.
If just commanding 'git pull', let me know I am correct.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process to update the code on your server would be as follows:

1. update the code in your local system.
2. add and commit to the repo using `git add .` `git commit -m "updated code"` `git push`
3. At this point the updated code is in the repo.
4. Now goto the directory where the repo was cloned on the server and do `git pull`

This should pull the updated code from the repo and the server will have the latest code.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I made it. After that, I had to type 'sudo service gunicorn restart' and 'sudo service nginx restart.'