# No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'

Tags: django

I upgraded from django 3.2.5 to django 4.0.4.
I know that this `'django.conf.urls.defaults'` must be deprecated.
My problem is that I don't get this error in the development environment but when I push to production, it shows the error. Why is this so???
Also I tried to locate the file so that I can change that line of code to the correct one but could find it's location. It's giving me this path which I can't see how to get to `(/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py))`

Comment: Have you upgraded to Django 4.0.4 at production environment ??

Comment: How do I do that, please?

Comment: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/step-by-step-guide-for-deploying-a-django-application-using-heroku-for-free/

Comment: I'm on digitalocean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553329/how-to-update-my-django-website-i-deployed-by-digitalocean

Comment: Also, generate updated requirement.txt file

Comment: I have done all the three but this one Now goto the directory where the repo was cloned on the server and do git pull. Where is this directory found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the possibles at my level , I had to revert to `django 3.2.5`